# How to automatically populate a “publish date” to be equal to today date, when selecting an item status to be = “Published”

Tags: 2013, list, development, javascript, issue-tracking

I have an issue tracking list inside my SharePoint 2013 enterprise server. The issue tracking have these columns:-

- Item status. In progress, Cancelled, Published
- Publish Date
- Duration in months
- End date.

Now currently I want to force this rule inside my list. when a user change an item status to be “Published” to have these values automatically calculated:-

- Publish Date = Today date.
- End Date =Publish Date + Duration in months.
- Users can manually change the publish date & duration in months. While End Date should not be editable.

So can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom editform.aspx via SharePoint Designer to make the end date "read only". You have to change the ControlMode from "Edit" to "Display".

[image]
There are also other ways with jQuery, JS or Powershell.

How to create a new, display or edit form is shown here:

https://afrait.com/blog/custom-new-edit-or-display-form-in-4-steps-en/

You can set the Publish Date via a Workflow to today, but if you want to update the item if it has changed a user can not change the date. The workflow will always set the date to "Today" after it finished.

You might consider setting the default value for publishing date to "today()", but that will only work once for the newform.aspx

The end date could also be a calculated column (then the user can not change the value).

Hope this helps somehow.

**UPDATE:**

You are right, calculated columns are only shown in the display form. Since you have SharePoint Enterprise you can customize you complete forms with *InfoPath*. There you can calculate fields on the fly. Maybe that's an option.

Comment: now for the end date it is best to have it as calculated date filed. so when users modify the publish date AND/OR duration in months it the end date get updated automatically.. but seems by default calculated field will not be shown inside edit/create forms,even in display mode, while it will be shown in display mode inside the quick edit grid.... i think this is not a great problem

Comment: second point now our customer requested that once the user change the status to be equal to "published" to have the publish date  automatically set to Today Date.. and automatically the end date get calculated,,, but they want the Publish date to still be changed by the users.. now if i set a workflow ,, then users will change the status to be Publoshed ,, but the publish date will not get updated till the user save his changes,, i am not sure if SP allow modifying a field value on the fly (Publish Date in my case) when another field get updates (Status changed to Published)?

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: i am trying to keep my list consistent with other lists, so using info path will create a new look and feel for the list.. now i am trying to keep things simple ,, for the "end date" field having it as a calculated field will work,, and i can create custom edit form and set it as display field.. so the only concern i have now is how to set the publish date to be equal to Today date, if the user change the status to be "Published"... of course i need this capability when add/edit items using the forms, or inside the quick edit grid ...

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a simple workflow that runs when the item is changed. Inside the workflow, you can check the value of `Item Status` and if it equals to `Published`, do your calculation!